# Cannot Apply Location and WindowSize from Config

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, binding

I want some properties of my `Window` saved to xml on termination and be reloaded and applied on startup.

I am saving the values to `XML` which is working fine so far.
I update the values in my ViewModel in the relating `ChangedEvents`.

```
[Serializable]
public class UserSettings
{
    public double WindowWidth { get; set; }

    public double WindowHeight { get; set; }

    //GridSplitter
    public double GridLength_Pixels { get; set; }

    public double WindowPositionX { get; set; }
    public double WindowPositionY { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `XAML`:

```
<Window x:Class="MonitorTool.Windows.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"       
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MonitorTool"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" 
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"         
    Title="Transport Monitor" 
    MinWidth="300"
    MinHeight="550"
    Height="{Binding WindowHeight, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    Width="{Binding WindowWidth, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"         
    Topmost="{Binding ElementName=TopMostCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}"
    Icon="{Binding Path=Icon, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    Left="{Binding Path=LocationX, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    Top="{Binding Path=LocationY, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"> 
[...]
```

The propertiesin my ViewModel are all quite the same so i'll just pose one here but it should be clear:

```
 public double WindowWidth
    {
        get { return _windowWidth; }
        set
        {
            _windowWidth = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("WindowWidth");
        }
    }
```

So I've created a Method called `ApplyUserSettings` which is called in `MainWindow_ContentRendered` where I load my Config and fill the properties with these values.

But nothing is happening and I got no idea where to look for a solution.
I've found alot of examples online where ppl store to defaultSettings but that doesn't seem like a big difference - so it should work the same with my own settings file.

Anyone an idea what could be wrong here ?

**EDIT:**

It seems like the Window startups with `MinWidth` and `MinHeight`.

**EDIT V2: The ViewModel:**

In `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if(MainWindowViewmodel.Instance == null)
        {
            MainWindowViewmodel.Instance = new MainWindowViewmodel(this);
        }            
        DataContext = MainWindowViewmodel.Instance;
        InitializeTray();
        TrayIcon.Visible = true;
    }
```

As you can see the value is set correctly but it seems like its not applied ;(
[image]

Comment: At what point do you create your ViewModel? Are you just creating it in the XAML? I.e. is a new view Model constructed every time your window starts up via the xaml?

Comment: @GingerNinja no I have an Instance I also have a splashscreen which uses the same vm but in there I use the same instance of it

Comment: There is a dozen of question in StackOverflow with the same context and many reasons on why binding properties such as width is not working. They are also proposing a lot of workarounds. Have you seen / tried any of these? If this so what is not working?

Comment: My immediate guess would be that your bindings are either not updating in time, or that they are disconnected somehow.
Have you tried using [WPF Inspector] (https://wpfinspector.codeplex.com)
I use it quite a bit when trying to debug similar issues. It would allow you to see the actual visual values as compared to your VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make a very simple test with the following view model:

```
public class UserSettingsVM: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _windowWidth;
    public double WindowWidth
    {
        get { return _windowWidth; }
        set
        {
            _windowWidth = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("WindowWidth");
        }
    }
    ...
```

}

And here is a code of a window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private UserSettingsVM _vm = new UserSettingsVM();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = _vm;
    }

    private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _vm.WindowWidth = 1000;
    }
}
```

It works like a charm. So it seems to me that you missed some small detail. Here are some tips:

1. Try to use a simplified code similar to mine. If it works for me, it should work for you.
2. Confirm that in `ApplyUserSettings` you are modifying the same instance of a view model as is used by a window.
3. Maybe some exception is thrown and catch under the hood what causes that binding does not work. To verify this scenario tell VS to break when any exception is thrown. To do so press *Ctrl+Alt+E* and select a check box next to *Common Language Runtime Exceptions*.
4. Go to *Tools->Options*. Select *Debugging->Output Window*. Under category *WPF Trace settings* set Data Binding to *Warning*. Now run your application in debug mode and open *Output* window. If there are any binding problems, you will see appropriate messages.

**EDIT:**

As to `MinWidth`, if it is set to X then `Width` cannot be set to a value smaller than X.

Comment: I got a sample working... Anyhow I cannot get my old app to do that for me... I passed your points from 2 ->4, I only got 1 instance of my VM, no special exceptions are thrown and there are no binding errors... Since I've se the MinHeight the use cannot "save" a value smaller that that and thats what's loaded from the config - not a problem then ...